# d3 sorting JSON objects with multilevel arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I would like to manipulate my data using d3 in a number of ways.
Currently, I sort using just one season object. I need to have the data set up this way.
But now I want to be able to go through multiple seasons.

I want each season to have its own color. And I need to also sort through each season and the players in it.

Previously I did this:

```
 mydata = data;

        mydata.season[0].players.sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.descending(a.stats.Points, b.stats.Points);
    });
    x.domain(mydata.season[0].players.map(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    }));

    y.domain([0, d3.max(mydata.season[0].players, function (d) {
        return d.stats["Points"];
    })])
```

Now I need to add color and do something more like this ( with _season actually being an array of seasons--instead of drilling down, looping through them all ). At the moment, d3 doesn't recognize this because it doesn't know how to treat all the seasons:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([d3.min(_season.year), d3.mean(_season.year), d3.max(_season.year)])
      .range(["red", "blue", "yellow", "darkgray"]);

    mydata._season.players.sort(function(a, b){
            return d3.descending(a.stats._currentStat, b.stats._currentStat);
        });
        x.domain(mydata._season.players.map(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(mydata._season.players, function (d) {
            return d.stats[_currentStat];
        })]);
```

Here is an example of my json:

```
{
  "season" : [
  {
    "year" : "2014",
    "players" : [
      {
      "name" : "Joe",
      "stats" : { "Points" : 100 }
      }
    ]
   },
 {
    "year" : "2013",
    "players" : [
      {
      "name" : "Mark",
      "stats" : { "Points" : 130 }
      }
    ]
  }
]

}
```

Do I need to manipulate my json before I send it to a function ( as in, make every player into a new array ) or does d3 have a method of handling/recognizing multiple arrays with multiple arrays in them?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this with d3.nest() but I'm having troubles at the moment.

Comment: d3 generally works better without nested arrays, if you can swing it.

Comment: How you found this [post](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) by Phoebe Bright yet?

Comment: Can d3 handle this though? Or do I have to break up the arrays in javascript and then merge them together as one?